# Best OOP method for a layout library

Tags: php, object-oriented

I had a code for a layout library which looked like :

```
$this->layout->setLayout($layout)->setTitle($title)->render()
etc.
```

Today I started writing a new code, simpler and smaller :

```
$this->layout->data(array(
    'view_name'     => 'layout_admin',
    'title'         => 'Administration',
    'js'            => 'admin/matrix.chat' 
))->view('admin/index');
```

The previous setters/add methods were like :

```
public function setDoctype($doctype) {
    $this->doctype = $doctype;
    return $this;
}

public function addJs($name) {
    if(!in_array($name, $this->js)) {
        $this->js[] = $name;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

The new data method :

```
public function data($data = array()) {
    if(isset($data['view_name'])) $this->ci->config->load($data['view_name']);
    else $this->ci->config->load($this->data['view_name']);

    // Mark as forbid because are stored in arrays and 
    // I can add values to those
    $forbid = array('css', 'js', 'rss');

    foreach($this->ci->config->config['layout'] as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($data[$key]) && !in_array($key, $forbid))
            $this->data[$key] = $data[$key];            
        else
            $this->data[$key] = $value;

        if(isset($data[$key]) && in_array($key, $forbid)) {
            if(is_array($data[$key])) {
                if(count($array) != count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE))
                    foreach($data[$key] as $key2 => $value2)
                        $this->data[$key][$key2] = $value2;
                else
                    foreach($data[$key] as $value2)
                        $this->data[$key][] = $value2;
            } else              
                $this->data[$key][] = $data[$key];
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I changed to this because of the many things that I can update for every page. And use ->setThing would be annoying. But I don't find that my code is so OOP.

Note that I'm using CodeIgniter.

What's the best oop code ? If you want more indications, please tell me I'm new and don't know how to  say more ;) .

Comment: You should add more details, especially code of your layout class.

Comment: It is done :) .

Comment: I like ->setThing, because i can use type ahead, also you can easily make a backtrace in the function and you have only backtrace for the manipulations of Thing and not for every other data in your class.

Comment: Your paths should start with '/', i.e /admin/index. So that they start at the root of the domain (especially if using mod_rewrite)

Comment: As John said, it's very effective. It's common practice in many frameworks... and in [Code Igniter itself](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html)!

Answer (score 1):

The core of your question is whether or not you should use setters ($tpl->setSomeParam()) or a simple array to bind template parameters. While using an array my not seem very OO, it's actually a pretty effective way of decoupling your data from your templates. As you've discovered, having to add a new setter to your layout manager every time you add a new parameter to one of your templates means the layout manager is tightly coupled to *all of your templates* – not good.

This is pretty common practice these days. [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org), [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#template), and many others do the same thing.